# Bootstrap V5 Modal not hiding via Javascript Unless Window Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm currently developing a react app and using normal bootstrap.The command to show a modal and toggle to one works fine; however the hide command doesn't hide the modal unless I make it a property on window.

For example:

```
const triggerSecondModalScreen = () => {
const element = document.getElementById("signUpModal2");
const currElement = document.getElementById("signUpModal");
if (element && currElement) {
  const currentModal = new bootstrap.Modal(currElement);
  const secondModal = new bootstrap.Modal(element);
  setLoading(false);
  // @ts-expect-error
  window.modal.hide(); // works fine
  // second.modal.hide() doesn't work
  new bootstrap.Modal(element).show();
  resetForm();
}
```

}

However, I notice that on Chrome dev tools **the _isShown is changing correctly to false**

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out a fix. The solution for anyone encountering this in the future is to not use the 'new bootstrap.Modal()' constructor syntax but to use the getInstance method on the modal.

Changing my code to the below caused it to work completely fine and without the use for creating a function on the window.

```
const triggerSecondModalScreen = () => {
const element = document.getElementById("signUpModal2");
const currElement = document.getElementById("signUpModal");
if (element && currElement) {
  const currentModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(currElement);
  setLoading(false);

  currentModal?.hide()
  bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(element)?.show();
  resetForm();
}
```

}

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.
I was doing something like `let boostrapModal = new Modal.getOrCreateInstance(modalEl, {});` I switched it to `let boostrapModal = Modal.getInstance(modalEl, {});` and it works now